# What was the reason when Bitcoin was $33,000, GBTC was about $33, but now Bitcoin is $54,000, and GBTC is $43?

Tags: funds, bitcoin-etf

I did see the question [Why does GBTC frequently not track Bitcoin's price?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/65051/why-does-gbtc-frequently-not-track-bitcoins-price), but exactly what happened when Jan 2021, Bitcoin was about $33,000 and GBTC was $33, and now (Apr 30, 2021) Bitcoin is $54,000, and GBTC is $43?

Comment: no answer, no comment, just closed. I think there are lots of intellectually curious people out there